# Request error in symfony with boolean in pass to form argument

Tags: php, forms, symfony, boolean, twig

I got a table in data base ID, json, status and everything works in another table and in this one I can save, read but can not take the data from repository and pass to form. Look:

that's my SliderType Form

```
    class SliderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('status', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'data' => $options['status'],
                'choices' => array(
                    "Aktywna" => 1,
                    "Nieaktywna" => 0
                ),
                'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
        ))
```

And here I need to pass from options resolver a status variable which is boolean, so in controller I done it look:

```
        //tworzymy formularz
        $form = $this->createForm(SliderType::class, $request, array(
         .
         .
        'status' => $slider->getStatus,
```

te problem is that another variables works perfect if i add only this i thrown a error:

```
Cannot read index "status" from object of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.
```

Any Idea what is wrong here? and the funny thing is that I got another controller with another table (structure the same) and all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the `HttpRequest` of symfony to the data of your form.

This is causing your issue

You should pass the entity which will be hydrated by the form. Give your slider entity to `createForm` method second argument

```
$form = $this->createForm(SliderType::class, $slider, array(
        'status' => $slider->getStatus));
```

Than you should tell the form to handle the request and extract data from request to hydrate your entity with your form.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

You should read the [form documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

Comment: nope, same here now just sayin is this index is not in entity slider, but the point is that i gave in SliderType option "mapped"=>false

`Cannot read index "status" from object of type "App\Entity\Slider" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.`

Comment: and very important is that i am building form no with entity in my database is only json_array table and nothing more, so if i get object slider and took out the variables from json i need to pass it to the edit form

Comment: everything works, but not this status, in another controller everything is same and there is no problem to pass status variable, in my controller i can use

`'status'=> $slider->getStatus()` same as with variable from json `'status'=>$status,`

Comment: Ok closed, i forgot to add mapped->false to ChoiceType in formbuilder so he looks this variable in entity :P but anyway thanks to show me good direction to look more about entity